# Returning promise after resolving promise in same function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I have library function which needs to return the promise to post something in DB after it resolves another promise.
I am trying to chain the promises but not working.

```
postIssue: function (issue) {
                  return getUserConfiguration()
                    .success(function (response, status, headers) {
                        var token = headers("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
                        if (token) {
                            _cookie = token;
                            if (issue.isValid()) {
                                var url = _baseURL + "/api/issue/";
                                var data = JSON.stringify(issue);
                                var config = {
                                    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
                                    headers: { "X-XSRF-TOKEN": _cookie }
                                };
                                return $http.post(url, data, config);
                            }
                            else {
                                return $q.reject("Issue doesn't have valid fields to submit");
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            $q.reject("There is no XSRF token on response header");
                        }
                    })
                    .error(function () {
                        $q.reject("Error getting user's configuration");
                    });
              }
```

When I call the function in my code where I use this library
It resolves and posts the issue correctly the data in then is shown of the first promise while I need the second one.

```
libraryAPI.postIssue(createIssue).then(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

data here is not of the second promise but the first one but Issue is created correctly

Comment: Use `then` instead of `success`/`error`!!!

Comment: Also you forgot `return`s before `$q.reject(…)`

Comment: @Bergi need to use success since need to access the headers

Comment: Uh, you can [access the headers](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage) from a `then` callback as well?

Comment: I have also edited my answer to include this information, I didn't realize you're using `.then()` on an $http outcome.

Comment: Wow it worked awesome. thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several points here.

1. Use `.then(successCallback, errorCallback)` rather than `.success()` and `.error()`.
2. The `.then()` callbacks has one parameter, and so does the error.
3. The `response` object in a successful callback also contain the headers and status. You can access them like so: `response.headers` and `response.status` (more information in the [Official AngularJS Documentation for $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage)).
4. You can either create a `$q.defer()`'ed variable and return it at the end (resolve/reject it in the logic), or immediately return a `$q.reject` or `$q.resolve`. I have edited your code and added `return` before `$q.reject`.

   ```
   postIssue: function (issue) {
       return getUserConfiguration()
       .then(function (response) {
           var headers = response.headers;
           var token = headers("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
           if (token) {
               _cookie = token;
               if (issue.isValid()) {
                   var url = _baseURL + "/api/issue/";
                   var data = JSON.stringify(issue);
                   var config = {
                       xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
                       headers: { "X-XSRF-TOKEN": _cookie }
                   };
                   return $http.post(url, data, config);
               }
               else {
                   return $q.reject("Issue doesn't have valid fields to submit");
               }
           }
           else {
               return $q.reject("There is no XSRF token on response header");
           }
       }, function (error) {
           return $q.reject("Error getting user's configuration");
       });
   }
   ```